# netcat6 in IPv6 local network

Tags: linux, networking, route

I have: `[ Host A ] -- [ gateway ] -- [ Host B ]`, whereas A and B are in different subnets.

Gateway configuration:

```
ip -6 link set enp0s3 up
ip -6 link set enp0s9 up
ip -6 addr flush dev enp0s3
ip -6 addr flush dev enp0s9
ip -6 route flush dev enp0s3
ip -6 route flush dev enp0s9
ip -6 addr add ::ffff:5:7:1:1/126 dev enp0s3
ip -6 addr add ::ffff:5:7:2:1/126 dev enp0s9
echo 1 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*/forwarding > /dev/null
```

Host A configuration:

```
  ip link set enp0s3 up
  ip -6 addr flush dev enp0s3
  ip -6 addr add ::ffff:5:7:1:2/126 dev enp0s3
  ip -6 route add default via ::ffff:5:7:1:1
```

Host B configuration:

```
  ip link set enp0s3 up
  ip -6 addr flush dev enp0s3
  ip -6 addr add ::ffff:5:7:2:2/126 dev enp0s3
  ip -6 route add default via ::ffff:5:7:2:1
```

I want IP to be a translated address from IPv4 (5.7.2.1 -> ::ffff:5:7:2:1).

The problem:
When I'm trying to ping host A from host B sometimes it pings sometimes it doesn't; from host A to host B the same behavior. When I'm trying to ncat -6 it doesn't work (gateway tcpdump says "Destination host is unreachable"). ping and ncat works only on and from gateway.

Route tables on the gateway:

```
::ffff:5:7:1:0/126 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
::ffff:5:7:2:0/126 dev enp0s9 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s8 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

The last fe80::/64 records are my ssh connections.

I suppose, the problem is in the route part, but the mystery for me is how to fix it.

### EDIT:

I SOLVED my problem, which was in flushing addresses `ip -6 addr flush dev enp0s3`.

Comment: AFAIR it's recommended to use no smaller nets than /64 for routing.

Comment: @rudimeier, yes, it's no smaller than /64, it's 126.

Comment: @marar In this case /126 is "smaller" than /64, because with /126 your network only has two usable addresses.

Comment: _::ffff:5:7:1:1/126_ - shudder! Why don't you use decent addresses? I'd expect that your problems would go away by themselves...

Answer (score 3):

IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses (i.e. addresses of the format `::ffff:192.168.0.1`) are not supposed to be used on the wire. They are intended to be used as internal identifiers for IPv4 addresses on dual stack sockets. When a dual stack (IPv6/IPv4) server process accepts a connection on an IPv6 socket from an IPv4 host, say `192.168.0.1`, it is internally converted to `::ffff:192.168.0.1`.

If a network interface receives a packet with an address of this format, it is a bug if it does not drop it.